# Create Gradient Background in HTML

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am new to html, and currently have set a background that is a single color. I have the code to change the background to the gradient color I want, but I cannot get it to work. The part of my code for creating the singular color background is:

```
</head>
<body>    
<!--Start of Product Banner-->
<body style="background-color:#6e6e6e;">
<div class="row">
<div id="header_region">
<!--Start of Header Logo-->
<div id="logo" class="two_thirds">
.....
```

The gradient color and code I would like to change it to is:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#6e6e6e 0%,#313131100%);
```

I have tried playing with this code to get it to work, but can seem to get the right syntax. How do I go about implementing this gradient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple linear gradient, from top to bottom (`#6e6e6e` to `#313131`), for the body tag:

```
body {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#6e6e6e, #313131); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#6e6e6e, #313131); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#6e6e6e, #313131); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#6e6e6e, #313131); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

You can find more information and examples about gradients in CSS3 [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp).

Comment: That is your web page? Looks good in Firefox. Did it worked for you?

Comment: Interesting, looks great in firefox, but has an issue in chrome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have two `<body>` tags and the child has inline CSS who is overriding the css style, please fix it and apply the css to the body.

```
body{
/* your code */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to this link http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ You can add colours like you would in Photoshop and it will create a gradient code for you as well as gracefully degrades when moving to older versions of browsers.

Comment: Don't just post a link as an answer, if you're going to link to that site, include the code that it would give him for his situation: http://jsfiddle.net/HQJsC/